# File upload through FTP in php

Tags: php, ftp

I want to upload a file to multiple FTP.But it is showing error :

`ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115)`.

Have a look to my code

```
foreach ($channel_details as $channel_list)
{

    if(isset($connection))
    unset($connection);
    if(isset($login))
    unset($login);
    if(isset($upload))
    unset($upload);

    $server = $channel_list['channel'];
    $ftp_user_name = $channel_list['username'];
    $ftp_user_pass = $channel_list['password'];

    $source='file_push.html';


   $dest='/public_html/'.$path.$file;


    $connection = ftp_connect($server) or die("Couldn't connect to ftp server");


    $login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    // turn passive mode on
    ftp_pasv($connection, true);

    if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

    $upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, FTP_ASCII);
    if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

    ftp_close($connection); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct.
Maybe there is a firewall problem?

See here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47110